# How do I set a Conda environment as an interpreter in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, conda

I have a tensorflow conda environment named "tensorflow_gpu". I use it with jupyter notebooks but I now want to use it with PyCharm as well.
How can I add the environment as an interpreter without deleting it and creating a new one from PyCharm itself?
I looked at [this link here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html) but it didn't help. The conda environment isn't listed.

Answer (score 1):

See [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html).

Click the gearwheel in `Project Interpreter` tab -> `Add Local` -> select your env in `Conda Environment` or just some `Virtualenv Environment`.

[image]

Comment: @Nissan Select your conda exe then.